# Does cucumber fruit re-grow on older vines?

Tags: pruning, cucumbers

I noticed that my cucumber fruit grows on younger vines. I did not cut off the suckers, and the plant is growing all over.

I wanted to know - do cucumber fruit re-grow on the older vines again later on, or do they only pop up in the younger areas of the plant, in new nodes? If it only grows on the younger areas, should I prune it near the bottom? Will it re-grow? Right now there are so many older vines that it's running out of space on the net. Or maybe I should just plant a new plant altogether?